# How to temporarily disable Omniauth authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I made a Facebook Devise authentication on my Rails 5 site. All the code and settings are standart.

But now I would like to temporarily disable it. I want to put a temporary redirect to `user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path` back to the calling page with some flash message "The facebook authorization is temporarily blocked".

But I haven't found any controller where I could set such a redirect. Or should I search for some callback? When I click `user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path` I see in console

> Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-25
>   14:21:39 +0300 I, [2016-10-25T14:21:39.699171 #23486]  INFO --
>   omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.

But no controller is called. How to do the redirect then?

I have the

```
    class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      def facebook
.....
      end
    end
```

controller - but it is called AFTER the www.facebook.com request - not BEFORE as I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController` which checks if `request.path == users/auth-facebook` and redirects to root with flash message.

Comment: I tried it, but seems like the `ApplicationController` is not called in this authorization sequence.

Comment: What is the path for `user_facebook_authorize_path`? If it's `facebook.com/....` then there's no way you can intercept it in your controller, you'll have to use JS to intercept `onClick` event. However, I suggest you just disable the facebook button in the UI and provide the explanation somewhere near that button.

Comment: The path is `/users/auth/facebook` and the controller is `users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru` . But actually the `passthru` action of the `users/omniauth_callbacks` controller is not called - at least prior to facebook call.

Comment: Ok, I mean, what is the href for the Facebook auth button? This is how it works, I assume: href is `facebook.com/oauth/....?callback_url=...users/omniauth_callback`. User clicks the button, he is redirected to facebook, then he's redirected back to the OmniAuth controller. You cannot intercept his click on the `facebook.com` link from your controller.